# Keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, motherboard

I have a keyboard that was previously working untill I unplugged it. When I boot it says no keyboard detected and I have tried a different keyboard and every usb port. I tried resetting the bios and it still doesn't work. I have an asus sabertooth 990fx r2.0 motherboard.

Comment: Have you tried the keyboard with another computer?

Comment: Its having problems on my raspberry pi and wont work, but I tried another keyboard with my computer and that didn't work

Comment: Are you plugging into the usb2 ports , and at least while having a problem avoiding the usb3 ports until it is working right? Try powering off completely also, with an usb keyboard that is not ever nessisary but if there was a resettable power problem at the port , removing ALL power , including standby power that keeps 5V on the usb in many cases, could re-start it.